How do I cleanly return errors from gRPC server handlers in rust?
Is there a fairly easy way to handle the conversion of errors from a gRPC server handling function in rust? I'm new to rust so maybe this is impossible, but I do see a lot of stuff around that shows that converting between error types is pretty common.
For example:
I have the following handler:
use tonic::{Request, Response, Status}
use stuff::{DoStuffRequest, stuff_server::Stuff}

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MyStuff {} 

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Stuff for MyStuff {
    async fn do_stuff(&self, request: Request<DoStuffRequest>) ->
        Response<DoStuffResponse, Status>
    {
        let data = ...; // get what should be valid json
        let jsonstr = String::from_utf8(data)?;
        let json = serde_json::from_str(&jsonstr)?;

        Ok(Response::new(DoStuffResponse{...}))
    }
}

What I would like is for the ? to take any errors from from_utf8 and from_str and convert them to Status so I don't have to have large match expressions that convert the errors.
I'm using thiserror to create an intermediate error type and then a conversion from my error type to Status, but rust doesn't seem to want to convert it.
#[derive(Error, Debug)]
enum MyStuffError {
    #[error("UTF-8 conversion error: {0}")]
    Utf8Error(#[from] std::string::FromUtf8Error),
    #[error("JSON error: {0}")]
    JsonError(#[from] serde_json::Error)
}

impl From<MyStuffError> for Status {
    fn from(error: MyStuffError) -> Self {
        Status::unknown(error.to_string())
    }
}

I get:
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `Status`
  --> src/server.rs:58:48
   |
58 |     let jsonstr = String::from_utf8(data)?;
   |                                         ^ the trait `From<FromUtf8Error>` is not implemented for `Status`, which is required by `Result<tonic::Response<DoStuffResponse>, Status>: FromResidual<Result<Infallible, FromUtf8Error>>`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <Status as From<MyStuffError>>
             <Status as From<h2::error::Error>>
             <Status as From<std::io::Error>>
   = note: required for `Result<tonic::Response<DoStuffResponse>, Status>` to implement `FromResidual<Result<Infallible, FromUtf8Error>>`


? can only convert errors if there is direct conversion from E to Status. It can't do E → E1 → Status because it doesn't know which E1 to choose (after all there may be several types that could go there). One solution is to use map_err to specify the correct type, e.g.:
#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Stuff for MyStuff {
    async fn do_stuff(&self, request: Request<DoStuffRequest>) ->
        Result<Response<DoStuffResponse>, Status>
    {
        let data = ...; // get what should be valid json
        let jsonstr = String::from_utf8 (data).map_err (MyStuffError::from)?;
        let json = serde_json::from_str (&jsonstr).map_err (MyStuffError::from)?;

        Ok (Response::new (DoStuffResponse {…}))
    }
}

